# cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]' for split

Tags: c#, .net

I am using the following code to split a string:

```
string sss="125asdasdlkmlkdfknkldj125kdjfngdkjfndkg125ksndkfjdks125";

List<String> s = new List<String>(sss.Split("125"));
```

However, I receive a compile time error:

> cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'

What is the correct way to split a string by another string?

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated your code to read `sss.Split` rather than `sss.split`, which 60% of the time is a syntax error every time. Please let me know if this is incorrect.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There is no overload for [`String.Split` which takes just a `string`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx), instead use the next closest match:

```
List<string> s = new List<string>(
    sss.Split(new string[] { "125" }, StringSplitOptions.None));
```

Comment: Now there is an overload which takes string: [Split(String, StringSplitOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0#system-string-split(system-string-system-stringsplitoptions)).
But It applies to .Net Core 2.0, Core 2.1, Core 2.2, Core 3.0, Core 3.1, 5, 6, 7, 8
and .NET Standard 2.1

Answer (score 54):

This confused me for a long time. Finally I realised that I had used double instead of single quotes. In other words, I had `x.Split(",")` rather than `x.Split(',')`.

I changed to single quotes and it worked for me.

Comment: Keep in mind that older .NET versions that are tied to a older C# version does not work with this. Was working on a project with .NET 4.8 and this didn't work. Had to do the convoluted approach below.

Answer (score 10):

You can just create a `char []`:

```
 List<String> s = new List<String>(sss.split(new char[] {'1', '2', '5'}))
```

or

```
 List<String> s = new List<String>(sss.split("125".ToCharArray()));
```

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx

Comment: OP want so split on 125, not 1, or 2 or 5

Answer (score 4):

That depends on what you wish to achieve. If you wish to split at the string "125" then do

```
sss.split(new[]{"125"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); //or StringSplitOptions.None
```

if you wish to split at any occurrence of 1, 2 or 5 then do

```
sss.split(new[]{'1','2','5'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a string array:

```
sss.Split(new[]{"125"},StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Or `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` if you don't want a blank string for before the first 125.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
//string = "friend&mom&dad&brother"
  string.Split('&')[int];
//string.Split('&')[0] = "friend"<br>
//string.Split('&')[1] = "mom"<br>
//string.Split('&')[2] = "dad"<br>
//string.Split('&')[3] = "brother"<br>
```

Comment: Have you tried running this? I just tried and got "Too many characters in character literal"

Answer (score 1):

For newer versions of .NET and .NET Standard now there is an overload method that takes string as a parameter:
[Split(String, StringSplitOptions)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0#system-string-split(system-string-system-stringsplitoptions))

Usage:

```
string[] result = stringValue.Split("anyStringSeparator");
```

[image]

Comment: ".NET Standard"... its time for microsoft officially declare it dead. Yeah, ".NET Standard 2.1" declares the method, but the only implemetaion is found in .net (core) - .net framework never will be .net standard 2.1 compliant

Answer (score 0):

this error/issue is not present in .NET Core 3.1 but does appear in .NET 4.7.2. This error came up while trying to use C# fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/) to test something and was not getting the same message in my project. The issue was that my project is using .NET Core compiler and the fiddle was not. Once that was updated in the fiddle, the error cleared.