# Argument `#1' cannot convert `string' expression to type `char[]'

Tags: unity-game-engine

The best overloaded method match for `string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

> Argument `#1' cannot convert `string' expression to type `char[]'

I'm trying to make a Text Dialogue but this error prevents me from compiling. What's wrong?

```c#
public TextAsset textFile;
public string[] textLines;

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
    if (textFile != null) 
    {
        textLines = (textFile.text.Split("\n"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot convert from 'string' to 'char\[\]' for split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055954/cannot-convert-from-string-to-char-for-split)

Answer (score 2):

`string.Split` has a couple of different overloads (combinations of parameters it can take), but none of them take a single string parameter. `"\n"` is a string literal, so it's an invalid argument.

One of the overloads takes a `params char[]`, meaning you can either pass an array of chars, or you can just pass a bunch of individual chars and it will make the array for you. So you can use `test.Split('\n')` because single quotes `'` denote a char literal rather than a string literal.