# How do I split text file using 3 empty lines as a delimiter?

Tags: c#

My text file:

```
TestTest
testtest
testtest



testtesttest
testtesttest
testtestset



testtsetse



testestset
```

I know how to split it with 1 empty line as a delimiter:

```
string file = File.ReadAllText(filePath)

string[] files = file.Split('\n');
```

When I use the next code it gives an error `cannot convert from string to char`:

```
string[] files = file.Split("\n\n\n");
```

But when I try:

```
string[] files = file.Split("\n\n\n".ToCharArray());
```

it's not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to define the result you want! 'Not working' is not helpful!!

Comment: @NewUser5111 Please, add expected result.

Comment: string[] files.Length must be 4 in this text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] files = file.Split(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: string[] files length must be 4 in first text file. Your code just splitting it with lines

Comment: when i writes that it gives me error. cannot convert from string to char

Comment: @NewUser5111 Switch to .Net Core 3.1 or use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055954/cannot-convert-from-string-to-char-for-split

Comment: yes i just tested it in net core and its working but in net framework, split function cant contain string. ty for your help :)

Comment: string[] files = file.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None); This is working thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read file line by line

```
string line;  
   
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);  
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
{  
    System.Console.WriteLine(line);  
}  
  
file.Close();
```